# How do I reset my OS X 10.6 password?

Tags: macos, password-recovery

I was following steps given at [makezine.com](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2007/07/howto-reset-a-lost-os-x-passwo.html) to reset a forgotten password for MacBook Pro (Mac OS X 10.6). But after doing

```
 #/sbin/SystemStarter
```

it doesn't give me back shell prompt `#`, as if it is doing some heavy computation. It's been like that for 10+ minutes. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Capitalization Matters! "/sbin/SystemStarter"  - try exactly as it is here with capitalization - this command starts the network services

Comment: Using instructions from July 2007 to change internals of an OS released in June 2009: Not a good idea.

Comment: @DanielBeck Do you know if `dscl . -passwd /Users/username password` is really necessary on 10.5 and 10.6 as [outlined here](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/08/03/how-to-reset-your-mac-os-x-password-without-an-installer-disc/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions on makezine are rather out of date and will not work on version 10.6 (and the section recommending `SystemStarter` was for versions that were old when it was written).  On 10.6, use the following commands to change the password for `yourusername`:

```
fsck -fy
mount -uw /
passwd yourusername
```

Notes:

- The first command will check the file structure of the boot volume; if it reports any problems, keep running it until it says the disk is OK.
- The second shouldn't print anything; if it does print something, it didn't work and you should check your typing and try again.
- After changing the password, use the `exit` command to continue booting normally.

Answer (score 0):

With the installer CD/DVD its even easier:

Resetting a forgotten Mac password is easier if you have an installer disk handy:

Boot from the Mac OS X installer disk by inserting it into the Mac and holding down the “C” key on boot.

Select your language preferences and then under the “Utilities” menu select “Password Reset” (it may say “Reset Password” instead, depends on the version of Mac OS X)

Select the hard disk that the forgotten password is on, then select the username of the forgotten password, you’ll then be asked to select a new password

Reboot as usual from the hard drive, using your newly reset password as the login!

This is obviously an easier method but it’s of no help if you own a MacBook Air with no DVD drive, or if you just don’t have the installer Mac OS CD laying around. In that case the other answer mentioned would be more appropriate.